# How to retrieve logcat in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

How do you get the output written to logcat back into the Flutter app that caused it? Or simpler asked: How to read logcat in Flutter?

**The problem is this:**

The app uses a stack of Android plugins to communicate with some custom hardware through Bluetooth. Those Android plugins write extensively to logcat. Now, for debugging, it would be **very helpful** to be able to read all the messages the App (**including native plugins**) has written to logcat. Question is, is this somehow possible?

How would you tackle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the plugin called [logcat](https://pub.dev/packages/logcat) on pub.dev.

Sadly, it seems to be no longer maintained and isn't updated for null safety.
But you can check out the source code [here](https://github.com/pharshdev/logcat) and see how the plugin gets access to the android logcat.

Because the logcat is a native thing, you'll have to use a MethodChannel to call a Java/Kotlin function:

```dart
// define MethodChannel
final platform = const MethodChannel('app.channel.logcat');
// call native method
logs = await platform.invokeMethod('execLogcat');
```

And the native part:

```java
public class LogcatPlugin implements MethodCallHandler {

    public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
        final MethodChannel channel = new MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "app.channel.logcat");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(new LogcatPlugin());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("execLogcat")) {
            String logs = getLogs();
            if (logs != null) {
                result.success(logs);
            } else {
                result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "logs not available.", null);
            }
        } else {
            result.notImplemented();
        }
    }

    String getLogs() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line);
            }
            return log.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "EXCEPTION" + e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

The code samples are from [github.com/pharshdev/logcat](https://github.com/pharshdev/logcat).
Maybe you can just fork the git repo and migrate it to null safety if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin called [logcat_monitor](https://pub.dev/packages/logcat_monitor) on pub.dev.

Its biggest advantage over the other logcat plugin is that it allows continuous monitoring of logcat messages.

Follows a screenshot example:

[image]

## how to use

Add the dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  logcat_monitor: ^0.0.4
```

1. Create a function to consume the *logcat* messages

```dart
  void _mylistenStream(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) {
      _logBuffer.writeln(value);
    }
  }
```

2. Register your function as a listener to get logs then use it in anyway within your app.

```dart
    LogcatMonitor.addListen(_mylistenStream);
```

3. Start the logcat monitor passing the filter parameters as defined in *logcat* tool.

```dart
    await LogcatMonitor.startMonitor("*.*");
```